# В toolbar внести кастомную View

Tags: android, android-studio, toolbar

Пытаюсь запихнуть в Toolbar свою TextView. В preview располагается нормально. При запуске приложения съезжает. Не могу понять в чем дело.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код активити

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".view.DetailActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/black">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_task_status_activity_detail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    tools:background="@color/colorTaskDoneBack"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    tools:text="Выполнено"
                    tools:textColor="@color/colorTaskDone"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_detail" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: а вы пробовали просто через ресурс меню сделать это?

Answer (score 0):

возможно проблема в том, что 
   tools:text="Выполнено" 
отображается только в макете, и вы не задаете в коде текст для TextView

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с комментарием выше. Попробуйте вместо tools:text="Выполнено" использовать android:text="Выполнено". А также вынести сам текст в ресурсы.